# Error says Unexpected Character, while back referencing in conditional regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Purpose is to match a pattern `"abc"` or `"<abc>"` but not `"<abc"` or `"abc>"`. The closing angle braces at the end should be matched only if the opening angle braces exist. The logic that I thought will work is as following

```
(<)?(abc)(?(\1))>
```

I'm trying to use back referencing and conditionals available. But the error says Unexpected character at second question mark `"?"` in regular expression. Incase needed I'm trying to do this on python.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for conditionals is slightly different, try this:

```
(<)?(abc)(?(1)>|)
```

This means:

If `(1)` (if group 1 was matched), then match `>`, otherwise (`|`), match nothing. But if you actually want to prevent the match of `abc>`, then you will need a negative lookahead:

```
(<)?(abc)(?(1)>|(?!>))
```

But that could be considered more complex than the simpler `<abc>|(?<!<)abc(?!>)` regex posted by Donal.

Answer (score 0):

That seems excessively complicated. Why not just:

```
<abc>|(?<!<)abc(?!>)
```

That is, either `<abc>` ***or*** `abc` without the `<` and `>` at all. It might mean a little more backtracking, but is much simpler to understand and will do the right thing!

Comment: That's because I have have a complex regular expression in place of "abc".

Comment: @DeepakRajHR Ugh; in that case, I'd actually consider some sort of multi-stage RE (possibly first simplifying things a bit so that I _could_ use something more like the above) rather than trying to do it all in one. Sometimes it takes too much effort to work out ways to combine everything into one piece of magic when it is much easier with a little external sequencing, conditionals and looping makes it trivial…